# Flutter video_player plugin - Change ClosedCaptionFile after VideoPlayerController initialization

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-video-player

I am using video_player plugin in my Flutter app and when I want to add a caption file I have to specifice a Future to the initialize method of VideoPlayerController. And I cannot find any way to change captions after the controller is initialized. But I have tried a way, I have added a method called setClosedCaptionFile in video_player source code and it is working. But I am wondering is there any other(correct) way to change the caption file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the plugin to the latest version, they added `setClosedCaptionFile` in the last update 2.4.0

check it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player/changelog)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I added this method to video_player (https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/5105).  But still thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

To add on omar answer you can also directly initialize the controller with the CaptionFile with the `closedCaptionFile` property of VideoPlayerController:

```
controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
url,
videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),  
closedCaptionFile: closedCaptionFile);
```